# Password Strength in Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0

Is it possible to active the Password Strength in Auth0 to **Excellent** in the **free** option subscription ?
I don't see the option in the configutation file

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an Auth0 database or Custom Db?

Comment: I am using Auth0 database

Comment: Where did you get the reference to the **Strong** level? Looking at the docs for password strength the most complex level is labelled **Excellent** and there's none labelled **Strong**. See https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-strength.